# cover text inside an image with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to make sure that all the writings are covered in a preloaded photo. for that im using firebase ml libraries(on-device, not cloud api).

I'm currently trying with the rect and giving it the coordinates that it reads from the block like that:

```
imageViewArray[i].setRight(blockFrame.right);
imageViewArray[i].setLeft(blockFrame.left);
imageViewArray[i].setTop(blockFrame.top);
imageViewArray[i].setBottom(blockFrame.bottom);
```

i didnt see any error but nothing change in my app.. where i wrong?

**another thing**: as i read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock.html#getCornerPoints()) getCornerPoint() create a Point[] with the axis x and y about all 4 corners.. can these be useful to me to create an imageview that is placed in the same area?

this is my onStart() in MainActivity:

```
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

        final Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
                textRecognizer.processImage(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                // Task completed successfully
                                Integer i = 0;
                                resultText = firebaseVisionText.getText();
                                output = resultText;
                                tvResult.setText(output);
                                for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                                    String blockText = block.getText(); //prende il testo e lo mette nella stringa
                                    Float blockConfidence = block.getConfidence(); //bho
                                    List<RecognizedLanguage> blockLanguages = block.getRecognizedLanguages(); //rileva la lingua
                                    Point[] blockCornerPoints = block.getCornerPoints(); //prende le coordinate della box
                                    Rect blockFrame = block.getBoundingBox();

                                    ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[50];
                                    imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(context);
                                    imageViewArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
                                    imageViewArray[i].setRight(blockFrame.right);
                                    imageViewArray[i].setLeft(blockFrame.left);
                                    imageViewArray[i].setTop(blockFrame.top);
                                    imageViewArray[i].setBottom(blockFrame.bottom);

                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                    }
                                });
}
```

Comment: you need to add imageviews to its parent.

Comment: you mean about layout or activity?

Comment: you are creating ImageView objects here `imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(context);` but you need to have parent and add this object to that parent. Maybe the parent view of the imageview where the image (on which you want to add these boxes)

Comment: can you give me an example about that? im trying but not work

Comment: what's your ImageView where you want to add these rectangles

Comment: over an other imageview that is occupying the whole screen (as a background), at the coordinates that firebase gives with Point[] or with Rect, by reading the text present in the image of the background imageview

Comment: so you need to call that imageview.parent() which will return ViewParent, cast it to ViewGroup and then add all the imageviews you have created to that parent with addView method. Also, try to have the parent of your original imageview as FrameLayout

Comment: im trying.. i do that: ViewParent vp = backimageView.getParent();
        ViewParent imgvp = ((ViewGroup) vp).getParent();
but when i try to add all imageviews i cant do .addView (error: cannot find symbol method addView(ImageView))

Comment: `ViewParent imgvp = ((ViewGroup) vp).getParent();` not needed. do something like this `((ViewGroup)vp).addView(imageView[i])`

Comment: with ((ViewGroup)vp).addView(imageView[i]) i have this error:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: if i create FrameLayout vpp = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout); where FrameLayout is the first container of all items in my activity_main.xml and then i do vpp.addView(imageViewArray[i]); app starts without errors but logcat continue to stamp writing and nothing change in my application

Comment: @user6327816 i solved with vpp = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.ConstraintLayout); and adding all imageviewarray to it. the problem is now that all imageview are smaller than the text block but yet the image that takes firebase is the getBitmap of the background imageview, so the coordinates should match the resolution of the app.. what could be the problem?